# Will an application compiled for iOS3 run on iOS4 ans ioS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, compatibility

Will an application compiled for iOS3 run on iOS4 ans ioS5?

if not compatible, what are the changes I have to do in my code to support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases it will work on iOS4 and iOS5. If compatibility issues will arise, it will always be unique in each case. There is no general approach to address the software compatibility issue when it comes to deprecated API's.

Comment: where can I find a guide that discuss this problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a good place, but you need to discuss a particular compatibility issue when one arrives. If you are just planning ahead and wondering, whether there will be compatibility issues, most likely there will be not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All versions of iOS have backwards compatibility as long as feature you used have been discontinued.